# SORT rows by date stored in Month form

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Actually, I am trying to sort my rows by Date field in which the date is stored in the form of like

```
DateC
===========
April, 2012
May, 2012
January, 2013

Date
===========
2013-01-03 10:51:23
2013-02-19 10:51:23
2013-03-26 10:51:23
```

But i am not able to sort it simply by just using `ORDER BY datec DESC`.

I can't use `ORDER BY FIELD (datec, 'December 2012', November 2012'...)` because there are two dates stored in my database. One is the timestamp i.e `date`, and the other is custom date i.e. `datec` which the user enters by himself. If the `datec` field is empty, it outputs the `date` field.

So, what I want is it should order the rows by both the date columns...

Please Help. If you have some questions, please ask mee....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is your datec field is a varchar and your date field a datetime/timestamp?

Comment: it's neither a varchar field, nor a datetime.. it has date stored iin this format `January 2012`, `March 2012`...

Comment: Hey @ShahbazSingh : What is your fields data type ? actually we understand that the date are stored in the form you told about but we need that you tell us what is the field data type for both :)

Comment: @LastBreath it is obviously string (*varchar*) `:)`

Comment: @LastBreath the field type for `date` is datestamp and for `datec` is `text`...

Comment: Hello @ShahbazSingh : Why you don't sort your rows by the date column instead of the datec ? Please let me understand did the datec column is a customer date version of the timestamp store in the date column ? Did i understand you well ?

Comment: Given your edits, what are your desired results?

Answer (score 1):

Date are stored in string format. so you need to use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(datec, "%M, %Y") DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one advantage of storing dates as string on the database. The ordering can still be applied provided that you need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` function to convert the string into valid dates.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
ORDER  BY STR_TO_DATE(datec, '%M, %Y') DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bd9f/2)

LINK

- [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

---

if you have time to alter the schema, the best way to do is to store those dates as `DATE` or `DATETIME` on the database. If you worry about the formatting of value during `SELECT` statement, there is still a function that called `DATE_FORMAT()` which convert the date into string at your desired format.

- [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Example,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%M, %Y') DateC
```

will yield

```
March, 2013
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9818)

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
ORDER  BY STR_TO_DATE(datec, '%M, %Y') DESC,
          date DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e990/2)

Comment: thxxx....it orders it well but i want to order it by both the columns...please...if you can help....

Comment: what do you mean by both columns? how many columns do you have?

Comment: there are 2....one is date which is the `datestamp` stored by mysql and one is `datec`, which is the custom date stored in form of 'March, 2012'...

Comment: can you update your question by adding sample records? I see only `datec` on the question, how does `datestamp` looked like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27260/discussion-between-j-w-and-shahbaz-singh)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for, using `STR_TO_DATE` and `COALESCE`:

```
select *
from yourtable
order by 
  COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(datec, '%M %Y'),date)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/732a5/6)

Comment: @ShahbazSingh -- can you elaborate?  It appears to order correctly in the fiddle.  Order by datec, unless it's null, then order by date?

Comment: it does it....but the output is like...`August, 2012` `July, 2012` which is ordering it well..but the timestamp date is at the end whcih is `31 MARCH, 2013`

Comment: @ShahbazSingh -- still not understanding -- updated fiddle using a comma in the str_to_date function: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23154/1 -- can you post a fiddle with sample data that isn't sorting correctly?